# Compare keys in json string using Unix shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a requirement where I need to compare the keys from the two strings using Unix shell script. I am creating the json string using the source string, so I need to make sure that all keys in the source string exists in the Json string. ie, the keys 8, 35, 79, 80, 44, 33 and 10 should exists in the Json string. The json string can be nested as well.

**source string sample** : `8=FIX|35=c|79=1|80=5|31=2|44=TEST|33=1.0|10=Test`

**json sample** : `{"8":"FIX", "35":"c", "79":[{"80":"5","31":"2"}], "33":"1.0", "44":"TEST", "10":"Test"}`

I see many examples with jq, but I cannot use jq now. Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking here. How to convert source to json, or how to verify the conversion? If you already have a conversion code, post it here. Also what's the logic around nested list for `79`?

Comment: Sorry if its not clear to you..I was looking for the code to verify number of tags after conversion, the number of tags present in the input should be same the number of tags present in the output. I should not loose any tags.

Comment: `jq` or `ruby` or `python` or `perl`  have json parsers. Any pure POSIX tool can be coerced by the solution will be fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the count of unique keys in each string here are a couple of ideas (I'm sure this can easily become parsing hell):

```
#!/bin/bash
source_string="8=FIX|35=c|79=1|80=5|31=2|80=9|31=3|44=TEST|33=1.0|9=sample|10=Test"
json_string="{8:FIX, 35:c, 79:[{80:5,31:2},{80:9}], 33:1.0, 44:TEST, 10:Test, 9:sample}"

# get the count of uniq keys on source_string in file "source_key_count"
grep -oP '[^\W]+(?==)' <<<"$source_string" | sort | uniq -c > source_key_count

# get the count of uniq keys on json_string in file "json_key_count"
grep -oP '(?<=[ ,{])[^\W]+(?=:)' <<<"$json_string" | sort | uniq -c > json_key_count

echo "== join =="
# show tabular comparation of counts: key source json
join -1 2 -2 2 source_key_count json_key_count | column -t

echo "== diff =="
# show differences between both files
diff source_key_count json_key_count
```

Comment: thanks for the update, it works for the input provided, but failed to process if there is any tags which are repeating as below: `String1="8=FIX|35=c|79=1|80=5|31=2|80=9|31=3|44=TEST|33=1.0|9=sample|10=Test"`                                                                            
 `String2="{8:FIX, 35:c, 79:[{80:5,31:2},{80=9}], 33:1.0, 44:TEST, 10:Test, 9:sample}"`  In the String 2 the 31 is missing.. :(

Comment: @kattoor Thanks for the feed back! Is this a typo on string2: `{80=9}`? should it be `{80:9}`?

Comment: @kattoor Please see updated answer... I not sure to understand well, you want to check key-value or only key, because the key 31 is in fact in string2, what is not there is the key-value 31=3, but neither is the key-value 79=1. In your question you said keys, that is what both initial answers correctly gave you... this is getting a little confusing and your initial sample data was missing info that now you are requesting.

Comment: thanks for the update..{80=9} is a typo.. :( and regarding the duplicate key, as i mentioned in the question, am concerned about the number of keys, no matter whether its duplicates or not. If the particular number is there in the input, it should be there in the output as well. As I mentioned in the second example, the 31 is repeating and it should be present in the output as well..I am using a complicated logic to populate the json string..so wanted to make sure that every field is considered while populating the output. hope you have understood what I am looking for. thanks again

Comment: @kattoor I think I got it, please try this oneliner to see if it is closer to what you need? `diff <(grep -oP '[^\W]+(?==)' <<<"$String1" | sort | uniq -c) <(grep -oP '[^\W]+(?=:)' <<<"$String2"| sort | uniq -c)`

Comment: @kattor Updated my answer hope this gives you nice ideas :).

Comment: this is perfect..working as expected..thanks a lot :)

Comment: just facing one issue, if I have the value like **126:20170727-21:30:00** in the json_string  its behaving differently. :(  here 126 is the key and timestamp is the value. as you know that its because of the repetitive ":" (semicolon) Can we consider the first ":" as the separator within the comma?

Comment: @kattor As I said on the answer this can easily become parsing hell. Please review updated answer, the regex for the json is now `(?<=[ ,{])[^\W]+(?=:)` which in a few words is matching a key which is one or more word or digit characters, preceded by any of this `, {` characters (notice the space) and followed by a `:`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of keys for each of your two inputs and compare them with nested for loops. This works for your samples:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXIT_STATUS=0

String1="8=FIX|35=c|79=1|80=5|31=2|44=TEST|33=1.0|10=Test"

String2="{8:FIX, 35:c, 79:[{80:5,31:2}], 33:1.0, 44:TEST, 10:Test}"

String1_keys=($(echo "$String1" | sed -e 's/=[^|]*|/ /g' -e 's/=.*//g'))
String2_keys=($(echo "$String2" | sed -e 's/:\[/:nested, [/g' -e's/[{}\[\]]*//g' -e 's/:[^,]*,/ /g' -e 's/:.*$//g'))

for key1 in ${String1_keys[*]}; do
    keyFound=0
    for key2 in ${String2_keys[*]}; do
        if [ "$key1" == "$key2" ]; then
            keyFound=1
            break
        fi
    done
    if [ $keyFound -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "key $key1 does not exist in String2_keys" 2>&1
        EXIT_STATUS=1
    fi
done

if [ $EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "All keys in String1_keys exist in String2_keys"
fi

exit $EXIT_STATUS
```

Depending on the format of the string you pump in, the sed statements on lines 9 and 10 may need to be modified.

Comment: thanks for the update, it works for the input provided, but failed to process if there is any tags which are repeating as below: `String1="8=FIX|35=c|79=1|80=5|31=2|80=9|31=3|44=TEST|33=1.0|9=sample|10=Test"`                                                                            
 `String2="{8:FIX, 35:c, 79:[{80:5,31:2},{80=9}], 33:1.0, 44:TEST, 10:Test, 9:sample}"`  In the String 2 the 31 is missing.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the feed back! Is this a typo on string2: `{80=9}`? should it be `{80:9}`?

Comment: It appears to work for me when the typo is amended. Like I said, you might need to fine tune the sed statements if your input varies more than I assumed in my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help.. looks need to tune again to work for repeating  numbers. but the other logic works as expected..